# LibGDX - Mouse sensitivity affected by framerate while cursor is catched

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

I am developing a small top-down view game. Camera can be moved by mouse within a certain view range, while the cursor is hidden using `Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true)` and an artificial one is drawn at the middle of the screen. This is how camera movement is handled:

```
    Vector2 deltaMouse = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getDeltaX() * mouseSensitivity, 
            -Gdx.input.getDeltaY() * mouseSensitivity);
    relativeCameraPosition.add(deltaMouse);
    relativeCameraPosition.limit(viewRange); 
    cameraPosition = playerPosition.cpy().add(relativeCameraPosition);
```

However, i've encountered a problem: game runs at over 1000 FPS normally, but after `Gdx.graphics.setVSync(true)` is called and FPS is being capped to 60 mouse sensitivity drops drastically, with camera movement being about 3 times slower.

I've inspected it a little bit and found out that this issue is related to a catched cursor. If i comment out `Gdx.input.setCursorCatched(true)` problem resolves and camera responsiveness is no longer affected by framerate. However, obviously, that way there is now second cursor floating all over the screen and striving to go beyond it's boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by manually calculating mouse delta as follows:

```
float mouseDeltaX = previousMousePosition.x - Gdx.input.getX();
float mouseDeltaY = previousMousePosition.y - Gdx.input.getY();
previousMousePosition.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
Vector2 deltaMouse = new Vector2(-mouseDeltaX * mouseSensitivity, 
        mouseDeltaY * mouseSensitivity);
relativeCameraPosition.add(deltaMouse);
relativeCameraPosition.limit(viewRange); 
cameraPosition = playerPosition.cpy().add(relativeCameraPosition);
```